# How do I upload my apk to Slack with Github Actions

Tags: flutter, github-actions

I want to upload my Flutter APK to a slack channel, Solutions I got were pretty outdated,

```
    name: CI

on:
  push:
    branches: [develop]
  pull_request:
    branches: [develop]

  workflow_dispatch:

jobs:
  build:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    defaults:
      run:
        shell: bash

    steps:
      - uses: actions/checkout@v2

      - uses: actions/setup-java@v1
        with:
          java-version: "12.x"
      - uses: subosito/flutter-action@v1
        with:
          flutter-version: "2.8.1"
      - run: flutter pub get
      - run: flutter pub run flutter_native_splash:create
      - run: flutter pub run flutter_launcher_icons:main
      - run: flutter build apk
      - run: flutter build appbundle
      - uses: actions/upload-artifact@v1
        with:
          name: release-apk
          path: build/app/outputs/flutter-apk/app-release.apk
```

This is the current workflow that I have, It builds and adds it to Artefacts on Actions.

[image: actions]

Answer (score 1):

Easiest solution is to use one of Actions available in Marketplace:

```
jobs:
  upload:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    name: Upload APK
    steps:
      - name: Upload to slack step
        uses: adrey/slack-file-upload-action@master
        with:
          token: ${{ secrets.SLACK_TOKEN }}
          path: build/app/outputs/flutter-apk/app-release.apk
          channel: apkchannel
```

Comment: Runs fine but throws an error on Path

Comment: Well you just need to set it to the place where you have it :)

Comment: @GrzegorzKrukowski im sorry for dumb question, but can you provide some info about how can i specify correct path? i know where is my file located, but whatever i do Path error still appears.